Computing error bars for the geometric mean across multiple datasets
I apologize because my understanding of statistics is somewhat basic. I will try to describe the problem as well as I can.
My colleagues and I have a graph where we measure the relative performance of different implementations of a set of computer programs. Each bar represents an arithmetic mean across N independent runs of each program for a given implementation. Each bar also has relative error bars (standard deviation).
We would like to add some columns that represent an aggregate of the performance of each implementations across all programs using the geometric mean. We've chosen the geometric mean because the scale of the numbers can vary quite a bit. Computing the geometric mean is not difficult, however, we would also like to have error bars for the geometric mean if possible. This is where we are most confused.
In order to produce error bars (standard deviation) for the geometric mean values, we would have to somehow average the standard deviations across all programs in our set. It's not clear how to do that in a way that would be statistically meaningful. I found that there is a formula outlined here for computing the average of standard deviations, but I believe this may only be valid for the arithmetic mean, not for the geometric mean.
